# MySQL unknown column in field list error. But there is a column

Tags: mysql

this query returns some records from table :

```
select * 
from yuk.sefer_yuk 
where sefer_id=1000569 
  AND bosaltma_tarihi='27/05/2021'
```

but this update query return error message :

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bosaltma_tarihi' in 'field list'

```
update yuk.sefer_yuk 
set bosaltma_tarihi='21/06/2021' 
where sefer_id=1000569 
  AND bosaltma_tarihi='27/05/2021'
```

I couldn't find the reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the first query works, and I see you added single quotes, assuming that this is a character or date field, the only reason I can think of is some kind of character set problem. Try to enclose table and column identifiers between **backticks**:

```
update `yuk`.`sefer_yuk` 
set `bosaltma_tarihi`='21/06/2021' 
where `sefer_id`=1000569 
  AND `bosaltma_tarihi`='27/05/2021';
```